# Oracle: creating a Matrialized View

Tags: database, oracle

I have a certain query that i have to do every day once 
this query creates a table that shows a certain sum qty for each day
instead i thought to do it in a materialized query in order not to create every day 
here is the query:

```
create table close_qty
as
select item_code,item_conc_code,tran_bran_code,sum(tran_qty) bal_qty
from tranhist a,itemmast b
where a.tran_item_code = b.item_code
group by item_code,item_conc_code,tran_bran_code
```

I am Trying To create a materialized view but i am getting the following error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00901: invalid CREATE command
```

here is my query

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW vwCloseQty
AS
select item_code,item_conc_code,tran_bran_code,sum(tran_qty) bal_qty
from tranhist a,itemmast b
where a.tran_item_code = b.item_code
group by item_code,item_conc_code,tran_bran_code
```

kindly advice if it will affect the performance and how can i solve the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW vwCloseQty(item_code,item_conc_code,tran_bran_code, bal_qty)
as
select item_code,item_conc_code,tran_bran_code,sum(tran_qty)
from tranhist a,itemmast b
where a.tran_item_code = b.item_code
group by item_code,item_conc_code,tran_bran_code;
```

You'd still have to refresh this every day though - so if you're only running the query once a day, a materialised view wouldn't really help.

Comment: Still the same error.as for refreshing every day i can implement refresh on command. is there any way to solve the issue

Comment: hmm, don't have an oracle instance here, looks right though - take out the group by and so on bit by bit and see when it starts to work alternatively do 'create materialized view vwCloseQty as select * from tranhist where 1 = 0' to start and build up from there.

Comment: same error INValid Create Command i am using oracle SQL*plus dont know if that would help

Comment: could you post the sqlplus session from start to finish with the error - just cut and paste.

Comment: Error accessing PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE
Warning:  Product user profile information not loaded!
You may need to run PUPBLD.SQL as SYSTEM

Connected to:
Oracle8 Enterprise Edition Release 8.0.6.0.0 - Production
With the Partitioning and Objects options
PL/SQL Release 8.0.6.0.0 - Production

SQL> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW vwCloseQty
  2  AS
  3  select item_code,item_conc_code,tran_bran_code,sum(tran_qty) bal_qty
  4  from tranhist a,itemmast b
  5  where a.tran_item_code = b.item_code;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW vwCloseQty
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00901: invalid CREATE command

Comment: You're running Oracle 8? It didn't have materialized views - it called them snapshots try 'Create snapshot...'

Comment: Can you Kindly Advise what is faster getting data from the indexed table as i am doing or getting it from a snapshot ??

Comment: They're 2 separate things. You can add indexes to snapshots as well, so it doesn't really matter (it maybe trickier with Oracle 8 though - I think you have to add the index to the underlying table from memory). If you don't add indexes to the snapshot though it will probably do full scans so that will be slow.

Comment: Can you help Me out with this one i have created a snapshot but it is not refreshing by itself can you kindly check the code here if there is something missing http://stackoverflow.com/q/12633906/1556893