# Oracle Snapshot Not Working

Tags: database, oracle

I have created a snapshot that takes data from 2 tables and has a refresh rate of 1 day. The snapshot data is not refreshing it is still the same. is there something that i am missing ?

Here is the code:

```
 CREATE SNAPSHOT test
 REFRESH COMPLETE
        START WITH SYSDATE 
        NEXT sysdate + 1
AS
select item_code,item_conc_code,tran_bran_code,sum(tran_qty) bal_qty
from tranhist a,
     itemmast b
where a.tran_item_code = b.item_code
group by item_code,item_conc_code,tran_bran_code
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle is this?  "snapsot" is extremely old terminology.

Comment: it is version 8.0 i cant use a materialized view also this code should work right ?

Comment: looks ok off hand - there's a background process that needs to run. you can tell if it's scheduled by looking in dba_jobs (I think that was available in 8). Have a look here 8.1 and 8.0 were fairly close, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a67791/mview.htm scroll down to 'SNP Background Processes and Interval'

Comment: This might help to, 8.1 again, scroll down to 'Advanced Troubleshooting of Refresh Problems' http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76959/reptroub.htm